# get method result in Java debugger

Tags: java, debugging, ide

Lets assume I need to debug some Java compiled code which provides debug information. So I can't change this code. For example I have

```
SomeClass object;
object.doAction1().doAnotherAction().doAnythingElse();
```

So I wanna inspect an object which doAction() returns and its fields. I know there's an evaluateValue action in most IDEs but I don't need to call method twice, because it could make changes that can't be undone. I don't care which IDE (Eclipse, Idea, Netbeans... ) to use, or even pure jdb. Probably there's an appropriate expression that fits into lots of languages debuggers, not just Java.

Comment: Netbeans has such a feature, “Step over expression” which allows stepping over method invocations showing each result. I don’t know of a similar Eclipse feature but I’m not using the most recent version.

Comment: Yep, that's what I've been looking for. Sorry for the delay. Unfortunately idea lacks this feature.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this information is useful, but if you are using Eclipse IDE, you can choose the expression you want the result and press "ctrl + shift + i", it get's the result of that expression.

Comment: Read the second sentence of the last paragraph. OP specifically considered and rejected this approach.

Comment: It calls the method. Try to create your own method and put there something like System.out.println('lol') Then press ctrl+shift+i and check the Console. It's evaluateValue.

Answer (score 0):

It's called 'Expressions' in Eclipse. If you go to the 'Debug' Perspective, you might see it.

**If you can't get to the Debug Perspective**

1. Click Window > Open Perspective > Debug.
2. If you don't see debug, click other and search for 'Debug'.

**Opening the Expressions Tab**

1. If you don't see it in debug mode, go to Window > Show View > Expressions.
2. If you cannot see Expressions in the Show View, click on 'Other' instead of 'Expressions'.
3. Inside the expressions, click 'Add new expression' and paste your code you want to evaluate in there.

Comment: OP specifically states that evaluating the expression multiple times is out because it may have side effects.

Comment: It calls the method. Try to create your own method and put there something like System.out.println('lol') And then add it to Expressions. It's the same as evaluateValue in Idea which I meant.